# Passing Component as a prop

Tags: reactjs

I have an object where I store a list of components like this

```
const componentsToUse = {
  "Key": Component,
  "Key2": Component2,
}

I use which component to use like this in jsx
{array.map((obj) => ( 
  { React.cloneElement(componentsToUse[obj.key], obj.props)}
)}
```

I get an error that says

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

If I remove cloneElement then the error goes away.

I also tried passing an element via the object like

```
const componentsToUse = {
  "Key": <Component />,
  "Key2": <Component2 />,
}
```

Doing so I first get an error that says propType validation failed because Component is expecting a prop which is required.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the component by key, and then render it as a component and pass the props to it.

```
{array.map((obj) => {
  const Component = componentsToUse[obj.key];
  return <Component {...obj.props} />;
}}
```